# Objective - C / Xcode. Loading a Subclassed UIViews xib within a UViewController

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode, uiview

I have created a monster and it is puzzling me.

I have created a rootViewController to handle the iOS apps views and data. This Controller has an xib which is facilitating it's looks. I have then subclassed a custom UIView Class and created its views with an xib. Im then trying to add the UIView class and its xib to appear in the RootViewControllers Views. SO the rootViewController is loading its NIb and Im trying to add this UIView subclass and install its views programatically.

My file hierarchy is as follows..

```
mockAppDelegate.h
mockAppDelegate.m
mockViewController.h
mockViewController.m
mockViewController.xib
colorPickerLoad.h
colorPickerLoad.m
colorPickerLoad.xib

Code inside h controller file.

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "colorPickerLoad.h"

@interface mockViewController : UIViewController
{

}

- (void)createColorPicker;

@end

In the controllers .m file:


@interface mockViewController ()

@end

@implementation mockViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {

    }
return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   [self createColorPicker];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
[    super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


- (void)createColorPicker
{
    colorPickerLoad *newload = [[colorPickerLoad alloc] init];

   [self.view addSubview:newload];

   [self.view setNeedsDisplay];

}
```

@end

Comment: Show your code that you have tried

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do it while the rootViewController is loading its nib, but you can achieve it after the loading is done AND before the view is really shown to the user.

What I really mean is to implement you viewDidLoad in the rootViewController implementation (if it's not a custom view controller yet, you make one to make one):

```
- (void) viewDidLoad { 
    UINib *nib = [UINib nibWithNibName:@"yourSubViewNib" bundle:nil]; 
    // Change the owner with real owner of the nib, if it's not the controller. 
    // This shall return the list of top views in your nib 
    NSArray *views = [nib instantiateWithOwner:self options:nil]; 
}
```

Comment: and then what do I do with NSArray *views after that? Please explain in a bit more detail

Comment: it contains the array of UIView objects (normally may be just 1 UIView designed by your nib). Add it however you prefer to the self.view, which is the parent view.